# shell scripting arithmetic operations

Tags: unix, shell, ksh

in general i will use expr inside shell scripts for doing arithmetic operations.

is there a way where we can come up with arithmetic operation in a shell script without using expr?

Comment: I suppose "Use `bc` instead" isn't *quite* the answer you're looking for...

Comment: @ignacio...could you pleasegive an example of how to use bc?

Comment: `PI=$(echo "4*a(1)" | bc -l)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you tried to read "man ksh" if you're using ksh?

"man bash", for example, has enough information on doing arithmetics with bash.

the command typeset -i can be used to specify that a variable must be treated as an integer, for example typeset -i MYVAR specifies that the variable MYVAR is an integer rather than a string. Following the typeset command, attempts to assign a non integer value to the variable will fail:

```
   $ typeset -i MYVAR
   $ MYVAR=56
   $ echo $MYVAR
   56
   $ MYVAR=fred
   ksh: fred: bad number
   $
```

To carry out arithmetic operations on variables or within a shell script, use the let command. let evaluates its arguments as simple arithmetic expressions. For example:

```
   $ let ans=$MYVAR+45
   echo $ans
   101
   $
```

The expression above could also be written as follows:

```
   $ echo $(($MYVAR+45))
   101
   $
```

Anything enclosed within $(( and )) is interpreted by the Korn shell as being an arithmetic expression

Comment: http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/OSUserG/_math_on_var_in_ksh.html
http://www.bo.infn.it/alice/alice-doc/mll-doc/impgde/node18.html

Comment: In all fairness, the ksh man page is, um, not so helpful.
The ksh88 man pages are even misleading, for example, explaining the _ variable, they tell you it relates to MAILPATH, but do not clearly explain what it is. (on solaris 9, HPUX 11.0 & 11i)

It is the argument(s) to the previously entered command, if it matters.

Answer (score 5):

Modern shells (POSIX compliant = modern in my view) support arithmetic operations:
+ - / * on signed long integer variables +/- 2147483647.

Use awk for double precision, 15 siginificant digits  It also does sqrt.

Use bc -l  for extended precision up to 20 significant digits.

The syntax (zed_0xff) for shell you already saw:

```
a=$(( 13 * 2 ))
a=$(( $2 / 2 ))
b=$(( $a - 1 ))
a=(( $a + $b ))
```

awk does double precision - floating point - arithmetic operations natively.
It also has sqrt, cos, sin ....  see:

http://people.cs.uu.nl/piet/docs/nawk/nawk_toc.html

bc has some defined functions and extended presision  which are available  with the -l option:

bc -l

example:

```
echo 'sqrt(.977)' | bc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

The precision and range of shell builtin `$(( <expr> ))` depends on the platform. On a 32-bit platform it's limited to 32-bit integers (unlike `expr`, which appears to support larger integers in a way that appears to be independent of platform).

(N.B - beware that while `^` is a valid operator in most shells, it does not mean 'to the power of', but rather XOR.)

Also - some shells are more forthcoming in this regard. Zsh, for example, allows floating point operations, such as `$(( 10/3.0 ))`